# 0 Byte File Extracted When Downloading Google Group Data

Tags: bash, google-groups

I am trying to download Google Group data onto my Windows 10 computer with bash 10.0. When I try retrieving the file from my bin, it is a 0-byte file called t.0, and has no text when I access it in Atom 1.27.2.

Here is the script crawler.sh I used as a guide, it requires installation of bash-4, sort, wget (1.17.1), sed (4.2.2-7), and awk(1.3.3). I have the newest versions:

https://github.com/icy/google-group-crawler

This is the forum I am trying to download:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/django-developers

I made the script executable with chmod 755, and they are in my local bin.
I entered the following code from the README into the main method of crawler.sh (~line 254):

```
export _GROUP="django-developers"
export _RSS_NUM=50            
export _HOOK_FILE=/path/to.sh
```

After that, I ran the testing command from the README in the shell:

```
./crawler.sh -sh              # first run for testing
./crawler.sh -sh > wget.sh    # save your script
bash wget.sh                  # downloading mbox files
```

I am new to using bash, so I am unsure of whether this is a simple error on my part, or an actual issue with the download.